# Orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^{r}$

Tags: vector-spaces, orthonormal

I have to prove that $\{f_1,f_2,..,f_r\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^{r}$ where:

$f_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}(1,e^{2i\pi\frac{j-1}{r}},e^{4i\pi\frac{j-1}{r}},...,e^{2(r-1)i\pi\frac{j-1}{r}})$

for $j$=1,2,...,r

I have no ideia how to even begin

Comment: The norm of each vector is indeed $1$!  What led you to believe otherwise?

Comment: Just got my mistake i was doign e^0=0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we have
$$
\langle f_j,  f_j\rangle = \|f_j\|^2 = 
\frac{1}{r} \left(1+\left|e^{2i\pi\frac{j-1}{r}}\right|^2+\dots+
\left|e^{2(r-1)i\pi\frac{j-1}{r}}\right|^2\right) = \frac 1r r = 1
$$
Now, for $j \neq k$, define 
$\alpha = e^{2 \pi i(j-k)/r}$ and show that
$$
\langle f_j, f_k \rangle = \frac 1r \left(1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \cdots + \alpha^{r-1} \right) = \frac 1r \frac{1-\alpha^r}{1-\alpha}
$$
Why is this equal to zero?

Comment: isnt $\alpha=e^{2i\pi\frac{j+k-2}{r}}$ ??? dont we get $\alpha^r=e^{2i\pi*C}$ wich is always 1 no matter the C?

Comment: To the first question: no.  Remember that
$$
\langle
(a_1,\dots,a_n),(b_1,\dots,b_n)
\rangle =
a_1 \overline{b_1} + \cdots + a_n \overline{b_n}
$$
That second bit is only true when $C$ is an integer.

Comment: Right. Dont we have $\alpha^{r}=e^{2i\pi(j-k)}$? So j-k is a integer and so $\alpha^r=1$

Comment: There you go! That'll do it.  Notice that wouldn't work for $\frac{j+k-2}r$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the dot/inner product on the complexes is defined in a special way.  Why not try it with $r=2$ or $3$ first?  That gives you $1/\sqrt{2}(1,1)$ and $1/\sqrt{2}(1,-1)$, which I think you'll agree are unit vectors.  Then try it with the cube roots of unity and remember that $e^{2i\pi/3}\overline{e^{2i\pi/3}}=1$ and you should be in business...

Comment: Try $\overline{e^{2i\pi/3}}$ (that is, `\overline{e^{2i\pi/3}}`)  instead

Comment: Thanks, I was in a hurry and didn't bother to look up the best way to do this.